# nuxt.config.js not loading .css files

Tags: javascript, css, nuxt.js

I am attempting to include my meta information (mostly visible in the static .css and .js files) to my Nuxt application by adding them into nuxt.config.js. I am expecting all of my global meta tags (charset, keywords, etc) as well as my CSS to be loaded when I reload the project on the page I'm testing on, however only using the local vue-meta section gives these desired results. I would like to be able to have most of my meta in the configuration file, so while leaving everything in each page is an option,it is not the one I would like to take.

I get no warnings or errors when loading the page, which makes me believe that it's not a problem, but I have just started using this file and would like to know if it is something trivial

The head I am trying to implement in nuxt.config.js is below. All file paths are valid (since they are what I use in the individual pages and they work just fine.

```
module.export = {
head:{
    meta: [
      {charset: 'utf-8'},
      {
        name: 'keywords', content: '~some keywords~'
      },
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/css/style.css' },
      { rel:'stylesheet', href:'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'},
      { rel:'canonical', href:'https://www.self.com' }

    ],
    script: [
      {src: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'},
      {src: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'},
      {src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js'},
    ]
  },
//...
}
```

I also have a similar body in my `css:` section, however that produced no results as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are missing a period ( **.** ) in your CSS link *href*, try:
href: '**.**/css/style.css'

Also you can try adding CSS as a property of your head object:

```
head {
link: [...],
css: ["./css/style.css"],
script: [...]
}/*end of head*/
```

If you try the second option then remove the CSS ref from your link array.

Good luck!

Comment: i'll mark is as the answer since it is what should have worked, but this specific (and irreplicable) problem was that the config file got divorced from the rest of the project

Comment: That's weird! But I am glad you are back on track with your project. Good luck